# Why I have a stop on next current element?

Tags: jquery

When I'm clicking span in `.current` li-element, I'm increasing my **current** on 1 and toggling classes, but when it's a second element I have a crash, whats wrong?

```
<div id="test">
     <ul id="n">
         <li><div class="q"><span>1</span></div></li>
         <li><div class="q"><span>2</span></div></li>
         <li><div class="q"><span>3</span></div></li>
         <li><div class="q"><span>4</span></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and **jQuery**

```
var current = 0;

$('#n li:eq('+current+')').addClass('current');

$('#n li.current').on('click','span',function(){

    $('#n li').removeClass('current');
    current++;    
    $('#n li:eq('+current+')').addClass('current');

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "crash"?

Comment: Change `$('#n li.current').on('click','span',function(){` to `$('#n').on('click','li.current span',function(){`

Comment: @Vivin Paliath `crash` mean stop.

Comment: Any crash?! Better call Saul!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector `li.current span` is dynamic because the target class `current` changes from element to element. So you need to use event delegation to target the dynamic element with the said properties

it should be

```
$('#n').on('click', 'li.current span', function () {
    $('#n li').removeClass('current');
    current++;
    $('#n li:eq(' + current + ')').addClass('current');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8txHj/)